# Updating edmx from VS 2017 showing error (Oracle database)

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, edmx, odac, odt

I am trying to update my edmx file using VS 2017 but each time I click on Update model from database option it is showing me the below  error . 
[image]

In my system `ODTwithODAC1120320_32bit` is installed. I could update the edmx from VS 2010 successfully.

Now I have installed ODAC for VS 2017 from [link](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odacmsidownloadvs2017-3806459.html)  but still the issue is coming. 
I have downloaded the `ODTwithODAC122011` from oracle site and tried to install but nothing is happening , it is just open a command window and after few seconds it got closed, seems like the installer is crashing.

Can someone help me to resolve this issue ? Do I need to install anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For VS 2015 or higher needes ODAC with ODT 12.2 + versions.

Downloaded and installed the lastest ODAC with ODT from [path](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odacdev-4242174.html). Now everything working perfectly.